# sumar cada cuadrante de una matriz en python

Tags: python

necesito ayuda con este codigo se supone que debo calcular la suma de cada cuadrante de una matriz sin importar el tamaño es decir la suma que estan por fuera de la cruz [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como los son el (2,7,3,5) debe de dar 17 que es la suma de ese cuadrante igual con los otros sin tocar los numeros de la cruz aqui les dejo lo que he hecho de codigo que es basicamente solo la matriz:

````
f = int(input("Digite cantidad de filas: "))
c = int(input("Digite candtidad de columnas: "))
m=[]
for i in range(f):
  m.append([])
  for j in range(c):
    dato=random.randint(1,5)
    m[i].append(dato)
for i in m:
  print(i,end=" ")
  print() ```
````

Comment: ¿y si tiene numero par de columnas o filas? ¿qué se debería hacer en ese caso?

Comment: que pasa si la matriz no es de 5x5 sino de 3x5? como se sumaria en ese caso?

Answer (score 1):

Acá, una forma de hacerlo. Puede que haya otras mejores:

```py
# hay 4 cuadrantes, uno en cada esquina.
# los elementos en cada cuadrantes se pueden identificar
# como 2 rangos, uno horizontal, y el otro vertical.

# arriba a la izquierda
# entre 0 y la mitad entera, tanto para fila como para columna
# por ejemplo, si es 5, el rango es [0,2]
up_l = (range(f//2), range(c//2))

# arriba a la derecha
# entre la mitad entera + 1, hasta al final
# por ejemplo, si es 5, el rango es [2+1, 5]
up_r = (range(f//2+1,f), range(c//2))
     
dw_l = (range(f//2), range(c//2+1,c))     # abajo a la izquierda
dw_r = (range(f//2+1,f), range(c//2+1,c)) # abajo a la derecha

# los elementos en cada cuadrantes se pueden
# referenciar para sumar
for cuadrante in [up_l, up_r, dw_l, dw_r]:  
   sum = 0
   for f in cuadrante[0]:
      for c in cuadrante[1]:
         sum+= m[f][c]
   print(sum)
```

Comment: Interesante respuesta, pero necesita una explicación de como funciona.

Comment: Genial, de todas maneras.

Comment: No soy el OP, pero le di un +1.